# How to get current view item in list view after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

While scrolling listview, I want to get current view which is having a textview and an image. 
Based on this I want to show starting letter of the first visible contact view item on top of list similar to our contact list.
 I tried with the following, But this is giving invalid index after scrolling.

```
HomeContactView extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener
```

overided corresponding methods

```
 @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
final ListView listView = mainListView;
        int location = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
}
```

Through this I am not able to get the current focused view and its elements.How to achieve this? Any help is really appreciable.

[image]

Comment: could you show me which code that give invalid index?

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20sticky%20listview%20header&es_th=1    or https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android+listview+header

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko : Thanks for the input. That library worked. What about the possibility of including the same in Recycler view

Comment: Do you want me to google instead of you again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is close to being correct. I would use the current parameter `view` and typecast it. And I check for the scrolling status (parameter `scrollState`). You want to avoid processing the ListView when user is still scrolling.

Code example:

```
@Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
       if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          final ListView listView = (ListView) view;
          int location = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

          View firstView = listview.getChildAt(location);
        }
   }
```

You can also override the other method, `public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)`. The benefit of this method is that you can get the **firstVisibleItem** as an integer type. I have used it and it is **accurate**.

Comment: I tried with links suggested by  Vlad Matvienko , But in listviews which implements dynamic image rendering breaks the library. Otherwise StickyHeaderListView is perfect.  So as per The Original Android , I tried again and it worked. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use RecyclerView / ListView's getFocusedChild() method? The method will work only if user focusing the view

Another way, you can do

```
View v = listview.getChildAt(listview.getFirstVisiblePosition());
String firstLetter = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview)).getText().toString().substring(0,1);
```

Comment: I tried with following . Now it is giving exception after few scrolls.

Comment: @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        if(scrollState== AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
            try {
                View convertView = mainListView.getChildAt(mainListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                TextView txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMain);
                Log.v(AppConstants.APPUILOG, "TextView text"+txtView.getText());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(AppConstants.APPUILOG, " Ex="+e.toString());
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can take the first row using `getChildAt` metgod:

```
View convertView = listview.getChildAt(listview.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

And than you can find your objects with the convert view, like this:

```
convertView.findRbyID(R.id.textview)
```

But it's recommended to use `RecyclerView...